# How to get argument passed to HTTP POST

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, httprequest

Here is an snippet of the code that I use in my RESTful webservice. I am sending a JSON data to the **create(Employee entity)**   method. I want to get that JSON data from the servlet request.

*The System.out.println(..)* method that I used gets printed which means **stringBuffer** is not NULL; yet nothing gets printed after ":" character [I am checking this in the glassfish logger].Besides, the POSTed enitity is being persisted to the database correctly.

I have googled many of the questions related to this on stackoverflow and other sites but nothing that I have tried works so far.

```
public class EmployeeFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Employee> {
@Context private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EmployeePU")
private EntityManager em;

public EmployeeFacadeREST() {
    super(Employee.class);
}


@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})

public void create( Employee entity) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;
    try{
        InputStream body = servletRequest.getInputStream();           
        stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        int d;
        while((d = body.read()) != -1){
            stringBuffer.append((char)d);
        }
    }
   
    catch(IOException e){
       
    }
    if(stringBuffer != null){
        System.out.println("the entity is: " + stringBuffer.toString()); // this line gets printed
    }
    super.create(entity);
}
// more code
```

}

Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: Silly question: can't you just do an [`HttpServletRequest.getParameter ("my parameter")`?](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)

Answer (score 2):

The server already consumed the request body in order to de-serialize it into the Employee entity for you automatically.  You can't read the same input stream again.

Comment: Thanks @Affe; it makes sense. So what is the verdict? am I doomed?

Comment: Doomed to what?  You just want to see the original string content?  Glassfish certainly has a way to dump the entire content of all requests into the log for you, I honestly don't remember how having not used GF in years, but I'm sure if you ask that question someone can tell you.

Comment: I am using the logger to just check things. I want the JSON data to process it in my app as I cannot use the EntityManager to retrieve an entity it just persisted. I give you +1 for taking the time to help.

Comment: If you just don't put an argument in your method signature, maybe it will leave the stream alone before getting to your handler?  Sorry, I could tell you how to do it in spring, but don't know EE as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'entity' used by the POST with the value of your stringbuffer.

check the tests or samples of a jersey /glassfish POST .

The POST.entity expects the value u want in the body of the POST.

Comment: Won't this be cyclic? I mean, I am trying to get the stringBuffer from the entity; how can I do the other way around; because apparently, the stringBuffer is empty at the start.